# How to make sequential contour in opencv-python from left to right

Tags: python, opencv, contour, text-segmentation

After segmenting a handwritten number using contours in opencv-python, it is giving a random output contour. How do I obtain one going sequentially from left to right and from top to bottom?

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: please explain **why** you need a special sorting

Comment: I made one of your tags more specific and rewrote the body to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort contours using below code:

```
def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
# initialize the reverse flag and sort index
reverse = False
i = 0

# handle if we need to sort in reverse
if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
    reverse = True

# handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
# the x-coordinate of the bounding box
if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
    i = 1

# construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
# bottom
boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
(cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
    key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

# return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
return (cnts)
```